# What is the exact type of this common mode choke?

Tags: automotive, can, common-mode-choke

I have this(on the picture) element missing from my PCB but I cannot find the exact model and specification.
The text on it says **G8276D3**. Can somebody recognize it?

[image: can transceiver common choke]

Comment: I’d guess it maybe from TDK/Epcos. As etherl  suggests you can bypass it if it is for an non critical system. It is a protection device  and is not required for operation, but the removal/bypass  of it may make the unit susceptible to interference. The part is a CAN bus common mode filter - this might help your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO8 in your circuit is a CAN transceiver and the lines where the filter is on are the CAN_H & CAN_L. And those pins are rated at ±58V as per the datasheet. So you can find one which is rated at that voltage, it will work or you can just bypass the filter in a low noise environment.